# "Element type is invalid: expected a string" when I import the class on index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I get

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>   for no reason when I access the react app

```
   6 | import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
   7 | import Counter from "./components/counter";
   8 | 
>  9 | ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById("root"));
  10 | 
  11 | // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
  12 | // unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
```

it hints at line 9 even though I exported and imported the class just fine

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: May be you are exporting multiple components from your `counter.js`. If so, then try importing it as `{ Counter }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use import you have to use export default keyword like this or you export multi object in the file you have to use

```
import { Counter } from "./component/counter";
```

My example how to use export default keyword

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const ACCInput = props => {
  const className = "form-control";
  const classNameError = "form-control is-invalid";

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={props.name} hidden>
        {props.name}
      </label>
      <div>
        <input
          className={props.className ? classNameError : className}
          id={props.id}
          type={props.type}
          name={props.name}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          onFocus={props.onFocus}
          onChange={props.onChange}
          onBlur={props.onBlur}
          value={props.value}
          disabled={props.disabled}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ACCInput.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.bool,
  id: PropTypes.string,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  onBlur: PropTypes.func,
  onFocus: PropTypes.func,
  required: PropTypes.string,
  disabled: PropTypes.string
};

export default ACCInput;
```